# Set Default Working Directory in Rstudio for Windows and End OneDrive Usurps

Tags: r, directory, rstudio, onedrive, windows-11

Whenever I start Rstudio, I notice the default working directory is Microsoft OneDrive. It gets to the point where I max out the available cloud data and can't make any additions to my work because files won't properly sync and save due to storage being at max capacity. How could I avoid this moving forward and is there a way to permanently/formally set the working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to solve the problem:

First, we need to locate and clean the working directory in one drive (and any other files that interrupt the syncing process). Once the syncing process is finished, open OneDrive and go to "Account" -> "Choose folders" and deselect any folders that you do not need syncing to OneDrive. Hit "OK" when you're done. Additionally, it is optional to unlink your computer from OneDrive completely.

If you want to set the *default startup directory* for RStudio on Windows, ideally to stop OneDrive syncs, here is the process:

In RStudio, you could either hold `Alt + T` or go to "Tools" -> "Global Options" -> "General". Then, set the "Default working directory" to the desired location. Once your directory is set, go ahead and restart the program and the rest should be smooth sailing!

using the `setwd()` function/syntax does the job for each current session. If you're tired of repeating the process every time you log in, this should do it.